# Leading zero with ui-mask on hours input from ui-timepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker, masking, leading-zero

I need to block anything except numbers from the angular ui timepicker input, so I used custom template with ui-mask. The only things changed from [default template from github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/timepicker/timepicker.html):

added

```
model-view-value="true" ui-mask="99"
```

to inputs with ng-model="hours", "minutes" and "seconds".

Then added timepicker as follows:

```
<uib-timepicker
    show-meridian="false" arrowkeys="false" show-seconds="true" 
    show-spinners="false"
    template-url="timepicker-tmpl.html">
</uib-timepicker>
```

When I try to enter a number with leadin zero in hours, like '09', it shows placeholder after I enter '9', and only will show '09' after I click elsewhere. I can enter any 2-digit numbers without leading zero in hours without any problems, and minutes and seconds don't have this leading zero bug at all.

Demonstration: https://plnkr.co/edit/iURaci7K3sHK8J9HzN49?p=preview

Could anyone please give me some tips on how to make hours behave the same way as minutes/seconds with leading zero numbers?